# friendship relation- sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I've searched through the site and have found some examples but not specific to my problem.

I'm  creating a frienship table in SQL and I want to make sure that each row is unique. for example: if **user x** is friend with **user y ---> user y** is friend with x.
i'm trying to make it impossible to enter (while creating the table):

```
user1ID  user2ID        timeStamp
11        10        01/01/2010 00:00:00
10        11        01/01/2010 00:00:00
```

I wrote this:

```
CREATE TABLE FriendRelationship(
    User1ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    User2ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    **CHECK (User1ID <> User2ID), /*User x cannot be a frien with himself*/
    CHECK ((User1ID <> all User2ID) AND (User2ID <> all( User1ID))),     
    /*if user x friend with user y ->  user y is friend with user x */**
    FtimeStamp DATETIME NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (User1ID) REFERENCES UserDF(UserID),
    FOREIGN KEY (User2ID) REFERENCES UserDF(UserID),
    PRIMARY KEY (User1ID, User2ID));
```

Comment: think this is wrong - ` CHECK ((User1ID <> all User2ID) AND (User2ID <> all( User1ID))),     `

Comment: and better use python_tail_code_style instead of CamelCaseCodeStyle. It's much more convenient for sql.

Comment: Use triggers instead  http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-check-constraint/

Comment: yes, it is wrong, it's not working.
i've tried to do the check while creating the table, and i'm not sure if it's possible. is it poosible to ensure it only with a query?

Comment: From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html): _The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines._ So, as @Serg says, using triggers is a common workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a different approach. Since it doesn't matter which user is `user1id` and which is `user2id`, I'd just decide that `user1id` must always be the smaller number (and it's the application's responsibility to sort the two IDs properly when it inserts them). having done that, the primary key on the combination of the two will ensure you don't have duplicate entries:

```
CREATE TABLE FriendRelationship (
    User1ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    User2ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FtimeStamp DATETIME NOT NULL,
    CHECK (User1ID < User2ID), -- The decision described above
    FOREIGN KEY (User1ID) REFERENCES UserDF(UserID),
    FOREIGN KEY (User2ID) REFERENCES UserDF(UserID),
    PRIMARY KEY (User1ID, User2ID)
);
```

Comment: first, thank you for your answer.

but then i'll have a problem- i won't be able to insert userID1: 4 is friend userID2: 2. which suppose to be possible and correct.
or am i missing something?

thank you

Comment: You would be able to insert such a relationship - you just need to make sure your application reorders them so that userID1=2 and userID2=4.

Comment: Did you note it's MySql?